# Are Boost.Qi rules always held by reference inside expressions that use them?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Say I have a simple type `foo`:

```
struct foo { void bar(int) { // do something } };
```

I would like to use Boost.Qi to parse integer fields out of a string and call `foo::bar()` with the resulting values. This can be done with semantic actions, like this:

```
std::string str;
bar b1, b2;
boost::spirit::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
    boost::spirit::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b1, _1)] >>
    boost::spirit::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b2, _1)]);
```

This has a lot of repetition, so I could remove some of the boilerplate like this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, int(), boost::spirit::qi::space> parse_bar(bar *b)
{
    return boost::spirit::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, _1)];
}

std::string str;
bar b1, b2;
boost::spirit::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
    parse_bar(&b1) >> parse_bar(b2));
```

This looks better and it works. However, sometimes I want to save the parser expression for later (for instance if I want to capture it by value for lazy use in a lambda function). In the original example, I can do the following:

```
std::string str;
bar b1, b2;
auto parser = boost::proto::deep_copy(
    boost::spirit::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b1, _1)] >>
    boost::spirit::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b2, _1)]);
auto lambda = [parser]() { boost::spirit::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), parser); };

// some time later
lambda();
```

This also works (although the call to `boost::proto::deep_copy()` is needed to ensure that none of the internal nodes in the AST are held by reference). My first impression was that I could apply the same `rule` refactoring to simplify the code above to:

```
std::string str;
bar b1, b2;
auto parser = boost::proto::deep_copy(parse_bar(&b1) >> parse_bar(&b2));
auto lambda = [parser]() { boost::spirit::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), parser); };

// some time later
lambda();
```

However, this results in problems inside the later call to `lambda()`. Based on my debugging, it appears that the `rule` objects returned by `parse_bar` are always held in the expression *by reference*, even after the call to `deep_copy()`. Since the `rule` objects are rvalues in the line that contains the call to `deep_copy()`, the references to them are invalid during the later call to `phrase_parse()`.

This would seem to suggest that `rule` objects are always intended to be lvalues with a lifetime that at least matches the lifetime of the expressions that reference them. Is this true? I think I might be misunderstanding a key concept of the library and am trying to do this the "wrong way." In my application, I don't have formal grammars; I'm looking for an easy, compact way to define a large number of similar parser expressions inline, with semantic actions that invoke bound member functions as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes.

```
<!-- reads the rest of your question -->
```

There are many inaccuracies in your code samples.

#### First Snippet

1. `bar b1, b2; // probably meant foo?`
2. `boost::spirit::phrase_parse` doesn't exist, neither does `boost::spirit::int_`
3. `boost::bind` is not ok as a semantic action
4. `phrase_parse` takes a skipper, you provide none

> Fixed:
>
> ```
>     std::string str = "123 234";
>     qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
>             qi::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b1, _1)] >>
>             qi::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b2, _1)],
>             qi::space);
> ```

#### Second Snippet

In the subsequent sample you have more mixup of `bar` and `foo`, you pass `qi::space` as a type param, `bind` fails to bind to `b` etc. etc. Without repeating the above and skipping the obvious errors

1. there is a fundamental problem where the template function needs to be used as `parse_bar<std::string::const_iterator>`. I'd say it no longer looks "nice".
2. the rule declares `int()` meaning you expose an attribute, but it's never assigned or used

> Fixed:

```
template <typename Iterator>
static qi::rule<Iterator, qi::space_type> parse_bar(foo *b) {
    return qi::int_ [boost::bind(&foo::bar, b, _1)];
}

int main() {
    foo b1, b2;
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    std::string const str = "234 345";
    qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), parse_bar<It>(&b1) >> parse_bar<It>(&b2), qi::space);
```

#### Third Snippet

Mostly the same issues, besides, `str` is not captured.

#### Fourth Snippet

Yes. See the first line of my answer

### Solutions

Think outside the box. You want "cute" syntax for binding a parser to an attribute out-of-band.

Note

- This is like going back to the Spirit V1 (classic) design. It's not the *spirit* [sic] of the library, so to speak
- If you want just that, use inherited attributes?

  ```
  std::string const str = "111 222";

  // use phoenix action 
  auto foo_bar = std::mem_fn(&foo::bar);
  px::function<decltype(foo_bar)> foo_bar_(foo_bar);

  // with inherited attributes
  qi::rule<It, void(foo*)> _foo = qi::int_ [ foo_bar_(qi::_r1, qi::_1) ];

  auto lambda = [_foo,&b1,&b2,str] { qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), _foo(&b1) >> _foo(&b2), qi::space); };

  // some time later
  lambda();

  std::cout << b1 << ", " << b2 << "\n";
  ```
- If you want 'magical' support for your types like `foo` and it is logically like assignment/conversion, use the traits: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize.html

### Live Demo

I always like to add a live demo, so here you go:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yd2wGQBlG9TQ8IvY)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

struct foo { 
    int value = 42;
    void bar(int i) { value = i; } 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, foo const& f) { return os << "{" << f.value << "}"; }
}; 

template <typename Iterator>
static qi::rule<Iterator, qi::space_type> parse_bar(foo *b) {
    return qi::int_ [boost::bind(&foo::bar, b, _1)];
}

int main() {
    foo b1, b2;
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    // snippet 1
    {
        std::string str = "123 234";
        qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(),
                qi::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b1, _1)] >>
                qi::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b2, _1)],
                qi::space);

        std::cout << b1 << ", " << b2 << "\n";
    }

    // snippet 2
    {
        std::string const str = "234 345";
        qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), parse_bar<It>(&b1) >> parse_bar<It>(&b2), qi::space);

        std::cout << b1 << ", " << b2 << "\n";
    }

    // snippet 3
    {
        std::string const str = "345 456";

        auto parser = boost::proto::deep_copy(
                qi::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b1, _1)] >>
                qi::int_[boost::bind(&foo::bar, &b2, _1)]);

        auto lambda = [parser,str]() { qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), parser, qi::space); };

        // some time later
        lambda();

        std::cout << b1 << ", " << b2 << "\n";
    }

    // snippet 4
    {
        std::string const str = "456 567";
        auto parser = boost::proto::deep_copy(parse_bar<It>(&b1) >> parse_bar<It>(&b2));
        auto lambda = [parser=qi::copy(parser), str]() { qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), parser, qi::space); };

        // some time later
        //lambda(); 
        //// no workey
    }

    // SOLUTIONS
    {
        std::string const str = "111 222";

        // use phoenix action 
        auto foo_bar = std::mem_fn(&foo::bar);
        px::function<decltype(foo_bar)> foo_bar_(foo_bar);

        // with inherited attributes
        qi::rule<It, void(foo*)> _foo = qi::int_ [ foo_bar_(qi::_r1, qi::_1) ];

        auto lambda = [_foo,&b1,&b2,str] { qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), _foo(&b1) >> _foo(&b2), qi::space); };

        // some time later
        lambda();

        std::cout << b1 << ", " << b2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the obligatory demo [Live On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yd2wGQBlG9TQ8IvY)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I shudder at the amount of errors in my original examples; that's what I get for trying to type them from memory!

Comment: The mantra is: provide SSCCE. That way you can simply run it on Coliru, Wandbox etc. Saves yourself and others lot of time.

Comment: PS. I didn't exactly elaborate on `boost::bind` vs. `boost::lambda::bind`, `std::bind` and `boost::phoenix::bind`. Long story short: use `phoenix::bind` in semantic actions. (And use them with Qi's placeholders)

Comment: Thanks; I apologize for not providing a better example to start with.